# Minimize $P(x,y,z)=(2x+3y)(x+3z)(y+2z)$, when $xyz=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Find the minimum value of the product $P(x,y,z)=(2x+3y)(x+3z)(y+2z)$, when $xyz=1$ and $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers.

I don't know how to go about this. AM-GM got really messy, and I don't know how to incorporate harmonic and quadratic root means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM we have $$(2x+3y)(x+3z)(y+2z)\geq 8\sqrt{36(xyz)^2}=48$$
since $$\frac{2x+3y}{2}\geq \sqrt{6xy}$$ etc

Comment: But this is not optimal, is it ? You cannot have $2x=3y,x=3z,y=2z$ all at the same time

Comment: Yes we can have all at the same time. [Wolfram Alpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+(2x%2B3y)(x%2B3z)(y%2B2z),+xyz%3D1,+x%3E0,+y%3E0,+z%3E0)